# How to find the Master Password on a Mac?

Tags: macos, passwords, filepath

I have a master password set up on my mac, and I have forgotten it.  I found the file path `/etc/master.passwd` though I am not sure if this is the right file.  I do not want to reset the master password, only figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably possible to try, especially if you recall something of the password. But it will take time to have the right tools and to do it, even weeks. Nobody can say that before trying. And some basic linux understanding is needed for the following instructions.

One of the best tool to try is this one http://www.openwall.com/john/doc/FAQ.shtml and you can find it in the KALI Linux distribution http://www.kali.org/

Once you upload your /etc/passwd and your master.passwd on KALI Linux, you can use `unshadow` to create a single file from the two (call it crackable.passwd) and then you can run

`john --rules -w:/path/to/my/wordlist crackable.passwd`

In a file called /path/to/my/wordlist you need to put as much words (newline separated) you can remember on your password. The --rules option does some mangling and permutations for you (on single words mostly, uppercase/lowercase, adding some numbers, adding special chars, etc...) but you might need to customize them. This is why I say it needs time to understand what you are doing.